# How to select alternatively 12 rows from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame containing 192 rows and I want to select 12 rows alternatively.

i.e. select first 12 rows, then select 25 to 36 rows, then select 49 to 60 rows.

How to do that in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple parts of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794602/selecting-multiple-parts-of-a-list), Also [Create a sequence of indexes by block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954495/create-a-sequence-of-indexes-by-block/)

Comment: Please read how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/. *Search and research*. Questions similar to like this have often been asked. Search for example "[r] select rows in dataframe" and this will often help you give you clues. see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21915056/4606130), for more complex work [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11612235/4606130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this vectorized using recycling technique in R (`df` is your data frame):

```
df[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 12),]
```

Comment: this worked.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the `iris` data as an example.

Simply use `iris[1:12,]` for the first 12 rows:

```
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
```

`iris[25:36,]` for rows 25 to 36, and so on.

Note that `iris` will be swapped to the name of your data frame. The comma is used to select either rows or columns. Thus, `iris[,1:3]` would select the first 3 columns of the data frame.

Comment: it will be more manual coding .. can you put in loop and extract the data from dataframe

Comment: Do you mean you would like a loop that does something to the first 12 rows, then something different to rows 25-36, etc?

Comment: no .. i just want to extract 12 rows alternatively which should be done by loop because the data frame is big